# What is the fewest number of moves it takes to completely interchange the red and blue pegs?

Tags: combinatorics

A board has 2n+ 1 holes in a line, with n red pegs starting in the first n holes, followed by a gap, thenn blue pegs in the remainingn
holes. The pegs may be moved either one hole forward into an empty
hole or a peg of one color may jump over a peg of the other color into an empty hole on the other side.
What is the fewest number of moves it takes to completely interchange the red and blue pegs?

The solution is written here:https://sumo.stanford.edu/old/smt/2007/Advanced%20Topics%20Solutions.pdf

But I can't understand the algorithem can you explain it?

Comment: Which of those 10 answers are you referring to?  Edit:  Must be #8.

Comment: @tilper number$8$.

Comment: "But I can't understand the algorithem can you explain it?"  How the heck can *anyone* explain something you don't understand when you just *read* a complete explanation? How the heck can we do that if we don't understand *why* you don't understand.  The very least you can do is point out *what* you don't unnderstand.  Otherwise all we can do is paraphrase with no faith you will understand *that*.  If you can't *ask* a question, you can't expect anyone to be able to answer it.

Comment: I suggest you try to follow the algorithm yourself step by step for some small numbers ($n=2$ or $3$ to start with), either by drawing the pegs after each step, or by finding some objects like coins and pens and pretend they are pegs.

Comment: Well, I apologize.  That is one of the *worst* written answers I've ever seen.  But still point out where specifically you have trouble with it.

Comment: @fleablood I can't understand What will happen after doing the first step of algorithem which side is the empty hole?

Comment: Draw a picture. Actually, so far as I can tell, this is the only possible course of action at all without ever moving pegs backeards.  You can't actually NOT do the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I like drawing pictures in Mathematica, here is an illustration of the algorithm for $n=4$.

To count the moves, of course, we don't need to follow the algorithm carefully: all we need to know is that no backwards moves are made, and therefore we achieve the lower bound of $n^2+2n$.

To make the answer self-contained, here's an explanation of the lower bound. Each of $2n$ pegs must move a distance of $n+1$, which is a total distance of $2n(n+1)$. If we moved a distance of $1$ at each step, that would be $2n^2 + 2n$ moves. But there are $n^2$ moves (for each blue-peg-red-peg pair) at which a peg jumps and moves a distance of $2$, so we save $n^2$ moves, and the lower bound is $n^2+2n$.

#### Starting position

[image: RRRR.BBBB]

#### Step 1: move red peg (1 move)

[image: RRR.RBBBB]

#### Step 2: move blue pegs (2 moves)

[image: RRRBRB.BB]

#### Step 3: move red pegs (3 moves)

[image: R.RBRBRBB]

#### Step 4: move blue pegs (4 moves)

[image: RBRBRBRB.]

#### Step 5: move red pegs (4 moves)

[image: .BRBRBRBR]

#### Step 6: move blue pegs (4 moves)

[image: BBRBRBR.R]

#### Step 7: move red pegs (3 moves)

[image: BB.BRBRRR]

#### Step 8: move blue pegs (2 moves)

[image: BBBBR.RRR]

#### Step 9: move red peg (1 move)

[image: BBBB.RRRR]

Comment: Here's a question.  If we ignore jumping backwards and after we choose a color to go first, is there any OTHER possible outcome but this algorithm?

Comment: There's no other complete solution without jumping backward. But we might make mistakes that don't involve jumping backwards at first, but get us stuck later at a place we're forced to jump backwards. So we still need some rule to tell us which peg to move when we have options.

Comment: For example, we could decide to begin by moving all four red pegs forward one space. That would be kind of stupid, and we'd have to undo several of those moves, but it is legal.

Comment: Oh.... I overlooked that.  So the answer to my question is "Yes" and my statement "Actually, so far as I can tell, this is the only possible course of action at all without ever moving pegs backeards" was simply incorrect.

Comment: It's dumb, but somehow I didn't think we even *had* options once we moved the red peg except to jump the blue.  It didn't occur to me that the red peg behind would actually also have an option.  (Of course, if we take it then, if we can't go back, there will only be red options till the end and it will end incomplete)